# Rails: Why do I get such a strange params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have an `Article` model which has `tags` and following `edit.html.erb`

## /app/models/article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  
  include Taggable
  
  has_many :child_articles, class_name: "Article",
                             foreign_key: "parent_article_id"
  belongs_to :parent_article, class_name: "Article", optional: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

end
```

## /app/views/articles/edit_form.html.erb

```
<title>_edit_form.html.erb</title>
 
 _edit_form.html.erb
 
 <%= form_with(model: @article, local: true, method: :patch, url: article_path) do |article| %>
 
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  
  <%= article.hidden_field :parent_article_id, value: @article.parent_article_id %>
 
  <p>
    <%= article.label :title  %><br>
    <%= article.text_field :title, value: "#{@article.title}" %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= article.label :text %><br>
    <%= article.text_area :text, value: "#{@article.text}", size: 200 %>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <div style="font-weight: bold;">tags</div>
    
      <%= article.fields_for :tags do |article_tags| %>
        <%= article_tags.text_field :name, value: "#{@article.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")}" %>
      <% end %>
      
    </div>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= article.submit %>
  </p>
 
<% end %>
```

For which I get on update following example hash:

```
>> 

params

=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"NK/5QEf/723CfgznpMCWT0/itHUj68gz5GmzD+nDzaLM6NILLex7/Co809QILxRUgegCwOppr/S8PN8vK3Avfw==", "article"=>{"parent_article_id"=>"", "title"=>"Überschrift", "text"=>"Toller Text", "tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Rails, Ruby"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Article", "controller"=>"articles", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

Why is

```
"controller"=>"articles", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"
```

out of the `"article"` key? It clearly belongs to the article information.

Yours sincerely

von Spotz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 3 params comes from the router (you probably have a `resources :articles` entry there, if you inspect the routes `rails routes` you'll see the template of the routes has an `:id` segment).

`params[:article]` comes from the from input fields: if you inspect the input elements you'll notice the `name` attribute is `article[title]`, `article[text]`, etc. Notice you only have an `article` hash there because of the inputs' names.

Maybe you are thinking of that in a different way, but for me it makes sense that those are separeted from the `article` key, because they serve different purposes: first 3 serves the purpose of finding a controller, an action and an article, the `article` hash serves the purpose of grouping the user input.

Comment: This is probably true. But is there a way to rearrange those informations into the "article" key for strong parameters? Or how would you handle this with strong parameters? Best wishes

Comment: Even if you put the `id` inside the `article` hash (which you can by adding a hidden field like `article.hidden :id` I guess or just by modifying the params hash), it's too dangerous to permit it, you would open the door for someone to change the ids of your objects. You really don't want the article id to have anything to do with strongparams.

Comment: And the controller and action params are not attributes of the article, so they shouldn't be related to the `article` hash either.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but then how does the controller#update methode know what object to update?

Comment: Also: isn't the assertion about security issues true for *every* params value except those with authenticity_token ?

Comment: The usual pattern is to do `@article = Artlcle.find(params[:id])` and then you use the object. About the security, yes, that's what strong params for, to only permit the fields that you want to allow the user to change, what I meant is that you should NEVER permit the user to edit the id of an object (unless you need that feature) so there's no point to include the id inside the `article` hash given that you will never permit it.

Comment: i delete this post